# How to find a list in another list with some different request

Tags: python, list

I want to get a graceful way that find a list in another list, Please check below sample. Thanks!

```
al = ['aaa', 'bbb']
bl = ['aaabbb', 'cccc']
```

I want to enumerate al, then if all elements in al is included in any one bl element, func return True, else return False, Below is my implementation, My question is that Can I move **for y in bl** into if statement in one line? or Is there any other better way? Thanks!

```
al = ['aaa', 'ddd']
bl = ['aaa', 'cccc', 'dddaaa']

for y in bl:
    if all( x in y for x in al):
        print 'exist'
        break;
```

Above code will output exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use nested generator expression with [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(all(x in y for x in al) for y in bl):
    print 'exist'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> flag=0
>>> for b in bl:
...      for a in al:
...          if a in b:
...             flag=1
...          else:
...             flag=0
...      if flag==1:
...        print "exist"
...        break
... 
exist
```

Comment: I need all elements in al is a sub string of any **one** element in bl. your code is not work. Thanks!